# unwanted syntax error saying unexpected token

Tags: node.js, syntax

so im trying to check if a message starts with something and im getting the error unexpected token{

ive tried messing with where the curly brackets are and nothing changed

```
        if(message.startsWith('kev') {

        });
```

```
C:\Users\La Fam\Desktop\kekbot_rewritten(tm)\ok.js:37
                if(message.startsWith('kev') {
                                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

i have no idea why this is happening

Comment: You are missing a `)` at the end, before the `}` - `if(message.startsWith('kev')) {`

Answer (score 1):

It needs another `)` before the curly bracket, and not after it. -

```
if (message.startsWith('kev')) {

}
```